# CS Amplifier without load or signal resistance

Tags: mosfet, amplifier

So I came across this interesting MOSFET question and thought I'd give it a try. I seem to be stuck on a couple of parts however, hopefully someone can see something I'm not seeing. Here is the circuit:

[image]

Here's my attempt at a solution for it and where I've been getting stuck:

(a) In the low frequency regime, capacitor CL becomes an open circuit. Performing a small signal analysis on M1 results in the following gain equation: Av=(Vo/Vsig)=gm1*Req, where Req=(r01||r02) since there is no load resistor RL at the output. gm1 is calculable since ID1 can be determined from the current mirror formed by Mb and M2 and the provided value of ID3. But the question specifies that r01=r02=infinity, however. Would this mean that the low frequency gain is indeed infinity?

(b) We can consider the high-frequency regime to determine the 3dB freq and therefore must consider the internal capacitances of M1. Since there is no signal resistance (Rsig=0), you can use the amplifier output to determine the 3dB freq. In particular, fH=1/(2*pi*(CL+Cgd1)*Req), where CL includes the relevant capacitances from the other transistors. But the result is fH=0 since Req=(ro1||r02)=infinity.

To me, these answers don't seem correct, but I cannot figure out where I am going wrong. The fact that this circuit doesn't contain a load resistance and neglects channel length modulation is puzzling.

Comment: What are r01 and r02? The resistances of M1 and M2? Something else? What are ID1 and ID3, the drain currents of M1 and M3? Those are my guesses, but please verify.

Comment: It's been a long time since I've looked at a circuit like this... But I think M3 is the key. What does it do? This may answer a lot of your questions

Comment: @JTaft121 You wrote: "But the question specifies that r01=r02=infinity, however. Would this mean that the low frequency gain is indeed infinity?" Do you know what channel length modulation is? If not, you should research it, and it's relationship to the output resistance of FET current mirrors

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy r01 and r02 are the output resistances of M1 and M2, respectively. Yes ID1 and ID3 are drain currents of M1 and M3. Am familiar with CLM, I assumed it was negligible here since Va=infinity. Will look into its relation to current mirror outputs, thanks

Comment: @Matt From what I understand, the output of the current mirror and the drain current of M3 sum to equal the drain current of M1.

Comment: yes, at least to a first approximation. But there is an output impedance, and it is related to channel length modulation. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Channel_length_modulation

Comment: So I disagree with @MathKeepsMeBusy but I'm a digital designer so I may be wrong.  I see the question as saying "ignore CLM".  So the gain is nominally gm of M1 times RL.  What's RL?  Ro of these transistors is infinite.  But the effective resistance of M3 is not RL.  It's a diode-connected transistor, which acts as a resistor of 1/gm.

Comment: @Matt To me this makes sense, since the presence of M3 would make up for the fact that there is no "RL resistor" on the output. Under your assumption, the low freq gain would be 1, and the formula for fH would produce a non-zero number, since gm (specifically gm3) is indeed calculate from the given info.

Comment: I'll add it as an answer.  If I'm wrong, I'll gladly accept corrections.

Comment: @Matt Yes, you are correct, low freq gain is indeed ratio of gm1/gm3, not 1 as I wrote above (I assumed gm1=gm3, but this is incorrect). Thanks

Comment: @Matt According to section 11.6 of https://wiki.analog.com/university/courses/electronics/text/chapter-11 , the output resistance of a current mirror is given by \$r_o=\frac{\frac{1}{\lambda}+V_{DS}}{I_D}\$ where \$\lambda\$ is the channel length modulation parameter. I guess if \$\lambda\$ is large, it may be ignored. Same formula here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Channel_length_modulation

Comment: OK. The problem statement seems to specify that \$V_A=\infty\$ and \$V_A=\frac{1}{\lambda}\$ so we have \$r_o=\infty\$, which the problem statement also specifies. So, now I am confused how one arrives at finite amplification. Perhaps it is the capacitances through the gate (in series) that provide the finite source-drain impedance that we need to solve this problem correctly?

Comment: @Matt OK. I am convinced of your position. The finite impedance is provided by M3. Because the W/L ratios for M2 and M3 are 4 and 80, the Q point of M3 will have ID3 20 times ID2 or 20mA. But now I am stuck finding r3 or gm3 or \$V_{DS}\$ or \$V_{GS}\$ (--all equivalent problems in that the solution of one will give the solution to all the others).

Comment: That's just a detail :). I don't remember the actual equations for these things, but it's more important to understand the concepts. You can always look up and equation, but it might not be easy to look this up and see "oh it's a diode connected transistor in parallel with an infinite impedance".

Comment: That was my goal with this problem (along with a bunch of others that I'm working on), to understand the concepts well enough to decipher what's actually going on. And yes, for the record, gm3 can be solved for since ID3 is provided and the MOSFET is in the saturated region.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the key is that M3 provides a finite load resistance.  It's diode-connected, which acts a resistance of 1/gm.  The low-frequency gain is therefore the ratio of gm of M1/M3.